# Communicate to Android Tablet via USB in AM335x

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, embedded, embedded-linux, libusb

I am developing an embedded device on TIs AM3352. It has a USB OTG port and I want to connect an android tablet to it and communicate to it via a C application. I have cross-compiled libusb-1.0 for usb communication.

First I tried to detect any device connection on the usb port using *libusb_get_device_list* function and print the device details like VID, PID etc if any device is detected. I am able to detect a pen drive using this test application. But when I try to detect my Android Tablet using this same test application, it is not happening.

Is there any addition settings that we have to do in kernel to enable my board to detect Android devices? Also should I use a different USB library to communicate with the device?

Comment: have you enabled **debugging mode** on your android device?

Comment: you might want to enable or allow access from android tablet, as @MilindDeore above mentioned. also what does dmesg on your AM3352 say when you plug in the android tablet?

Comment: @MilindDeore I did not enable debuggind mode when I tried it first time. But, even after enabling the debugging mode I am not able to detect the device

Comment: @bytefire dmeg does not show any information about the usb device connection. When I connect my smartphone to the am3352 board it is showing the dmesg outputs like vid pid etc but when I connect this tablet that I intend to use it is not showing any prints

Comment: Try plug-out and plug-in AM3352 again.

Comment: then it might be worth increasing kernel log level. this will be noisy but might give us more info about what happens when the tablet is plugged in. run as root `echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk` and then plug in the tablet. also does the tablet show up correctly on some other linux system?

Comment: Just to double check, is AM3352 taken power from Android tablet (if so, is it getting sufficient power as per requirement) or does it require external power?

Comment: @MilindDeore Still no luck.. I am able to detect my Huawei phone.. Just after I connect the device, the prints are coming. But it not happening for some other devices like Moto and lenovo.. I will probably have to enable something extra in kernel to support these devices but I am not sure what to enable.. [Edit]The AM3352 board is powered externally from an adapter

Comment: @bytefire There are no prints coming even after exectuing "echo". Also the tablet is not getting detected with my linux PC running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: well then problem seems to be with tablet not with your code or libusb :)

Comment: @bytefire looks like it.. but it seems to be with some particular brands/devices. As mentioned I am able to detect my Huawei phone but this is not happening with a Motorola phone. So there could be something that we need to enable to detect with these devices. Let me try.. :) Thanks..

Comment: i think that enabling comes at a higher level. rn the usb device itself is not being detected, so it looks like an issue with the tablet or cable connecting it to your dev board. i'd suggest getting to show up on a working linux system (or any other system!) and then connect to am3352 device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue was with the particular type of USB cable. When i tried a different type it is working